# how riscv-template works?

Tags: riscv, chisel

There's a repository called **riscv-template**:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/project-template

It looks like that when I want to make my own version of risc-v rocketchip SoC by adding source code, using this template will help me.

If I use normal repository (https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip), and modify code inside it, just compiling the source code worked.

But, in the case of **riscv-template**, when I add my own project by making directory, it seems that 'make' in *verisim* directory requires me to make *Generator* and *TestHarness*.

Just indicating CONFIG flags in my own made 'Configs.scala' does not work.

What '*Generator*' and '*TestHarness*' does and why do I need in this repository, and what should I put in that files.

It seems that there's no information about how rocketchip soc is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

TestHarness is the Chisel test harness which instantiates your top-level design and attaches the memory and serial console.

The Generator provides the main function for Scala to run. Take a look at the example project in project-template to see how you would create your own.

https://github.com/ucb-bar/project-template/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/TestHarness.scala